# How do you change the value of a variable in an instance in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have an instance of an object which is added to a list and then the data is displayed in a windows form c#. Is it possible to change the data of the instance through the windows form?

```
Person Joe = new Person("Sam", "Smith", "12.05.1992");
person.Add(Joe);
```

This is the instance of the person then added to a person list.

```
textBox1.Text = person.Forename;
textBox2.Text = person.Surname;
textBox4.Text = person.DateOfBirth;
```

This is how I am displaying it in the form through text boxes so that you can input a new name and subsequently save the changed data.

This was my thought..

```
person.Forename = textBox1.Text;
```

but think I need something after it.

Comment: what do you mean by "I need something after it"? what exactly is your problem with what you already have?

Comment: What is a person? I mean, of what type is `person`? From what you provided, it could be `List<Student>` or if `Student` inherits from some `Person` class maybe `List<Person>`, but then `person.Forename` etc. wouldn't make sense.

Comment: says it is unable to cast the object of type

Comment: Where does it say that? What object? What type? You know your program, we don't. A `List<Person>` does not have Properties like `Forename`, `Surname` or `DateOfBirth`. How can you assign that to the textboxes?

Comment: I saw the error of creating a student then trying to print out a person I have changed the code above like I have in my program but I still cant change the name in the form and make it change in the instance

Comment: Maybe `textBox1.Text = person[0].Forename;` is what you are doing. If so, `person[0].Forename = textBox1.Text;` should change Joe's Forename. Where do you want to set the Forename? Inside the textBox1.Changed event? Or at the press of a button? Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ?

Comment: I want to change it in the text box on the form but then press a button and change it from there on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I understand your `Person` class looks something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string forename, string surname, string dateOfBirth)
    {
        Forename = forename;
        Surname = surname;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Forename + ";" + Surname + ";" + DateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

So your Form should look like that:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Person Joe = new Person("Sam", "Smith", "12.05.1992");
        Persons.Add(Joe);

        textBox1.Text = Persons[0].Forename;
        textBox2.Text = Persons[0].Surname;
        textBox3.Text = Persons[0].DateOfBirth;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Persons[0].ToString()); // before change
        Persons[0].Forename = textBox1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(Persons[0].ToString()); // after change
    }
}
```

But I don't quite get, why you would want a `List<Person>` and not just one `Person`. If you have more than one `Person` in the List, how do you know, which one to display and subsequently change?

PS: I would strongly advise you to use `DateTime` as the Type of your `DateOfBirth`. You'll be in a world of trouble if you ever want to actually work with the date of birth...

Comment: Thanks think i need to make some changes to my code. Thanks for the help and tips

Answer (score 0):

Tyr text changed event  or text validated event 
eg:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person.Forename = textBox1.Text;
        }
```